# Proving that the Fourier coefficients of a functional determine it

Tags: functional-analysis

Proving that the Fourier coefficients of a functional determine it

I have the following exercise, taken from old homework of a functional
analysis course:

> Let $\mu\in C(\mathbb{T})^{*}$. Define the Fourier coefficients of
>   $\mu$ by  $$ \hat{\mu_{n}}=\mu(e^{2\pi int}) $$
>
> Prove that if $\mu_{1},\mu_{2}$ have the same Fourier coefficients
>   then $\mu_{1}=\mu_{2}$

I have tried to prove this by calculating $\mu_{1}(f)$ for $f\in C(\mathbb{T})$
and tried to prove that it is the same as $\mu_{2}(f)$.

My problem is that I have used 
$$
f=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(n)e^{2\pi int}
$$

which I was told that is not necessarily true in $C(\mathbb{T})$,
but rather in $L^{2}$.

I was also told that I should of used the Stone-Weierstrass theorem,
but I didn't understand how.

Can someone please explain how can I use S-W in order to solve the
question ?

Comment: Coefficients are not furry. I assume you talk about Fourier coefficients?

Comment: This is a hairy question.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - Thanks for the correction. Spellcheck didn't catch it for obviousreasons so I assumed I typed it right :P

Comment: Dang, your edit ruins my remark :-).

Comment: @copper.hat - it's all in the edit history ;-)

Comment: You could use Fejér's theorem. Or Stone-Weierstraß. And Hahn-Banach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $\mu = \mu_1-\mu_2$,  the question boils down to showing that if $\hat{\mu}_n = 0$ for all $n$, then $\mu = 0$.

Let me use the notation $e_n(t) = e^{i 2 \pi n t}$.

Suppose $\mu(f) > 0 $ for some $f \in C(\mathbb{T})$. Let $p_n = \sum_i \alpha_n^i e_i$  be a sequence of trigonometric polynomials converging uniformly to $f$. Since $\mu(p_n) = \sum_i \alpha_n^i \mu(e_i)$, we see that for sufficiently large $n$, we have $\mu(p_n) > 0$. In particular, we must have $\hat{\mu}_k=\mu(e_k) \neq 0$ for some $k$.

Hence if $\mu$ is non zero, the $\hat{\mu}_k$ cannot all be zero.